# Eureka Client PKIX Path Building Failed

Tags: rhel, netflix-eureka, sslhandshakeexception

I have an application that I am running on RHEL, with 4 servers. The application, the registry and two others. When I run the start script all of them run just fine except the registry. I can access it, but when I check the registered instances it does not see itself as UP, when I should be able to. I check the log and I am getting this

```
java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

In my start script I am passing `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` with their values passing as environment variables. In my trust store I have added the registry server certificate (which is its own server certificate. I have even added the root/intermediate certificates, and the other servers certificates) I still have this problem. I ensured the trust store is JKS. I verified that the certificates are valid, my pathing, and the spelling for any errors.

Like I said, the application starts and this is the only error.

What else can I do?